# Comparing an array and arrayList indexes

Tags: java

I was wondering if there was any way that i could compare and index of an arrayList and a array. I tried using the > operator and that didn't work.

I have tried something like this

```
if(ArrayVar[i] > arrayList.get(i) )
```

and i get errors.

Comment: What do you mean, "compare and index of an arrayList and a array"?

Comment: arrayList.get(i) and Array[i]. I want to compare and see if one is bigger than the other

Comment: What is the content of your list and the content of your array ?

Comment: @Steffan Harris How did it fail ? What are the types of arrayList.get(i) and  Array[i] , and what were the actual values ?

Comment: the array is of type Object, and the arrayList is an Integer type

Comment: you can't compare an Object with an Integer; if you know that the Object is actually an Integer, then you will need to typecast it ((Integer) myObj) then make the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the array is of type Object and the arrayList is an Integer type. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Assuming the array acutally holds Integers as their Objects, you can cast that to an Integer and do the comparison then.

If the array doesn't have Integers (or any kind of number) how do you expect to compare them?

Comment: @Steffan, the SO convention is to [upvote answers which you find useful](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer). Since you accepted the answer, you obviously found it useful - please consider upvoting too. I did it now, for justice :-)